# What are the difference between SQL jdbc driver versions 7.4 and 8.2 in terms of features?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mssql-jdbc

I have only found out the differences in system compatibility between the two versions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-version-compatibility

I am looking for the difference in features between the two JDBC driver versions.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases ?

Answer (score 0):

In the [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) of 8.4 JDBC driver, Microsoft mentioned that,

> Version 8.4 is the latest general availability (GA) version. It
> supports Java 8, 11, and 14. If you need to run on a Java runtime
> older than that, see the Java and JDBC specification support matrix to
> see if there is a supported driver version you can use. **We are
> continually improving Java connectivity support. As such we highly
> recommend that you work with the latest version of Microsoft JDBC
> driver**.

So the version upgrade should be for improving the java connectivity support which should be the performance improvement between 7.4 & 8.2 drivers.